# Macro is running very slowly when other workbooks are opened

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am using a VBA tool in Excel and when I try to save the tool through VBA then the tool will be saved within 10 seconds when there are no other workbooks open. Even when other workbooks are opened macro should save within 10 seconds.

If other workbooks are open it is taking more than 10 minutes to save the tool, but this tool/code is not linked with any of the open workbooks.  When I try to save this tool through VBA, I think it is calculating all formulas in other workbooks and then saving this tool.

I am using this tool very frequently and I don’t want to close all other workbooks every time when I am using this tool.

Is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If calculations are causing the delay this should confirm it

Place it in ThisWorkbook module

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    enableCalcs True
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    enableCalcs False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    enableCalcs False
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    enableCalcs
End Sub

Private Sub enableCalcs(Optional ByVal opt As Boolean = True)
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    Application.Calculation = IIf(opt, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            ws.EnableCalculation = opt
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If I add the below mentioned code, then the Automatic calculations will be disabled only for this workbook.  <br> **Is there a code to disable Automatic calculations to all open workbooks?**  <br/>  `Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)  

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic  

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) 

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

End Sub`

Comment: Can someone please tell me **how to use line breaks**?

Comment: **Is there a VBA code to disable Automatic calculations to all open workbooks before saving and enable it after saving?**

Comment: I edited the anser to disable Calculations for all open Workbooks